# find doc count for nested aggregation of elasticsearch using java api

Tags: java, elasticsearch

```
searchRequestBuilder.addAggregation(
            AggregationBuilders.nested("skuFilter").path("skus")
            .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders
                .filter("sizeFilterCondition")
                .filter(FilterBuilders.boolFilter().must(FilterBuilders.termsFilter("skus.gender", "Dad\'s", "Mom\'s")))
                .subAggregation(
                    AggregationBuilders.nested("sizeValues").path("skus.attribute")
                        .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("attributeId").field("skus.attribute.attribute_id").size(AGGREGATION_SIZE)
                            .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("attributeValue").field("skus.attribute.attribute_value").size(AGGREGATION_SIZE)))))
            .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("fromAge").field("skus.from_age").size(AGGREGATION_SIZE)
                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("toAge").field("skus.to_age").size(AGGREGATION_SIZE)))
            .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("gender").field("skus.gender").size(AGGREGATION_SIZE))
            .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.min("min_price").field("skus.sale_price"))
            .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.max("max_price").field("skus.sale_price"))
    );
```

above is my Aggregation code

I am trying find docCount of gender as follow

```
Nested agg = searchResponse.getAggregations().get("skuFilter");
        StringTerms terms = (StringTerms) agg.getAggregations().getAsMap().get("gender");

    List<Bucket> termsList = terms.getBuckets();
    for (Bucket bucket : termsList) {
        System.out.println(bucket.getKey());
        System.out.println(bucket.getDocCount());
    }
```

I am getting irrelevant ans.

what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Nested agg = searchResponse.getAggregations().get("skuFilter");
```

to

```
Nested agg = searchResponse.getAggregations().getAsMap().get("skuFilter");
```

Comment: This solution is not woking